# LINQ Group multiple keys where with one let variable

Tags: c#, linq

I was wondering if it is possible to do something like this.
I added multiple keys where one of the key is coming from a method call via let.
I don't know how to integrate the **category** into the group

group o by {category, o.City}

```
var query = from o in Feedbacks.ToList()
            where o.FeedbackID > 1236
            let category = Category(o.RecommendationScore)
            group o by {category, o.City} into scores
            select new{
                       scores,
                       count = scores.Count()
                       }; 


public string Category( int score )
{
    if(score == 10 || score == 9)
        return "Promoters";
    else if(score == 8 || score == 7 )
        return "Neutrals";
    else
        return "Critici";
}
```

Comment: you just need `group o by new {category, o.City}` instead of `group o by {category, o.City}`, it's just a syntax error.

Comment: If you want more performance use tuples instead of anonymous classes. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples

Comment: Please don't change your question to include the answer. If you have discovered an answer then please post it as such.